# Swap font and background color using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-hover

I display 40+ boxes on a page:

```
<div id="primary">
    <div class="box" style="background:....">
        <a href="" style="color:....">box1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background:....">
        <a href="" style="color:....">box2</a>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

As you can see I set background-color and text-color. On hover I want to swap the colors:

```
      $(".box").each( function () {
          $(this).data('baseColor',$(this).css('background-color'));
          $(this).find('a').data('fontColor',$(this).css('color'));
          $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:
                       $(this).data('fontColor') }, 500);
          },function() {
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 
                       $(this).data('baseColor') }, 1000);
          });
        });
```

The animation of the background-color works but I can not change the font color of the a element. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you're using jquery UI, taht animate call isn't going to do anything.

Comment: the animation works, I have jQuery color plugin included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brandon mentioned, you need [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) (or something ;) to animate non-integer properties.

The bigger issue is the change of context in your `each` callback: inside the `hover` callback methods, the value of `this` won't always be what you want. Also, creating new jQuery objects (with `$(...)`) is relatively expensive. Try:

```
var cssBox = {
    backgroundColor: $('.box').css('background-color'),
    color: $('.box').css('color')
};

var cssLink = {
    backgroundColor: $('.box > a').css('background-color'),
    color: $('.box > a').css('color')
};

$(".box").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $this_a = $this.children('a');

    $this.data('baseColor', $this.css('background-color'));
    $this.data('fontColor', $this_a.css('color'));
    $this.hover(function() {
        $this.animate(cssLink, 500);
        $this_a.animate(cssBox, 500);
    }, function() {
        $this.animate(cssBox, 1000);
        $this_a.animate(cssLink, 1000);
    });
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3fYPV/).

Comment: thanks, no the background-color changes to font-color, but font-color stays the same

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: there is nothing there to change the font color. I'll try and add something.

Comment: it seems that the script doesn't find the font-color

Comment: Did you make the change in line 4? Previously you were setting the 'fontColor' data on the 'a' element.

Comment: Try changing `animate` to `css`.

Comment: I did a bit of debugging and it seems that he saves the correct color but can't apply it; changing animate to css does not work

Comment: the animation is appied to the box but not to the a element. I need to animate the color of the a element

Comment: @ArtWorkAD - one last thing: it would be _much_ better/cleaner/maintainable/etc if you could just do this in css (or at least, just add/remove a styled class to the div and set the colours in css :)

Comment: Ah yeah, fair enough. I wonder if there is a way to animate the addition of a class.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can't animate colors on it's own; you'll have to use the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color).

As for swapping the colors around, you'll have to have an interim variable to temporarily store one of the colors. Some pseudocode would be this:

```
var bgCol = $(this).backgroundColor()
$(this).backgroundColor = $(this).textColor();
$(this).textColor = bgCol;
```